# How to create random users in PHP to seed database

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to seed my database with example users. I would like each user to not be identical, however the code I have produces 10 identical users. How do I structure the loop to create a new random user before pushing to the array?

```
$frst = array('Bob','Joe','Kim','Gary','David','Vasili','Fred','Seaton','Steve','Lou','Greg');
$last = array('Jones','Allen','Darling','Foster','Johnson','Hall','Lynch','Wilson','Baldwin','Largent','Shelton','Porter');
$role = array('Architect','Electrical','General','Mechanical');
$rand_frst = array_rand($frst, 4);
$rand_last = array_rand($last, 4);
$rand_role = array_rand($role, 4);

$users = [];
$i = 1;
    $user = [
    'first_name' => $frst[$rand_frst[0]],
    'last_name'  => $last[$rand_last[0]],
    'email'      => $frst[$rand_frst[0]] . '@' . $last[$rand_last[0]] . '.com',
    'password'   => $last[$rand_last[0]],
    'company_id' => rand(1, 5),
    'username'   => $frst[$rand_frst[0]] . $last[$rand_last[0]],
    'zipcode'    => rand(98101, 98999),
    'role'       => $role[$rand_role[0]]
    ];
while ($i <= 10) 
{
    array_push($users, $user);
    $i++;               
}       


var_dump( $users );
```

I tried putting the $user array inside the while loop, but I get the same result

Comment: do your randomization inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always trying to access [0] the first returned array value. You're only building a random selection on one occasion (before the loop). That's why your values are the same for 1-10. You need to re-randomize inside the while loop.

```
$frst = array('Bob','Joe','Kim','Gary','David','Vasili','Fred','Seaton','Steve','Lou','Greg');
$last = array('Jones','Allen','Darling','Foster','Johnson','Hall','Lynch','Wilson','Baldwin','Largent','Shelton','Porter');
$role = array('Architect','Electrical','General','Mechanical');
$users = array();
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10)  // no need to use <= since it will evaluate < first and stop
{

    $rand_frst = array_rand($frst); // no idea why you wanted to select 4 by random,
    $rand_last = array_rand($last); // when you're only using 1. so i've removed
    $rand_role = array_rand($role);

    $user = array(
    'first_name' => $frst[$rand_frst],
    'last_name'  => $last[$rand_last],
    'email'      => $frst[$rand_frst] . '@' . $last[$rand_last] . '.com',
    'password'   => $last[$rand_last],
    'company_id' => rand(1, 5),
    'username'   => $frst[$rand_frst] . $last[$rand_last],
    'zipcode'    => rand(98101, 98999),
    'role'       => $role[$rand_role]
    );
    array_push($users, $user);
    $i++;               
}   



var_dump( $users );
```

Comment: I'm getting NULL returns with this code for all but the numeric rand functions. And I did include the $frst, $last, and $role vars in the loop.

Comment: The full code is updated above, sorry I didn't pull over the arrays defined and we no longer need to specify `[0]` because we're only pulling 1 random at a time.

Comment: There you go! I had the `[0]` left in from when I had ten of these, before trying to refactor using the while loop. Good eyes, sir!